# Requirements for linear function of gamma distribution

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

If X is a gamma distribution, and Y = aX + b. What are the requirements for `a` and `b` for Y to be exponential?  I suppose a must be greater than 0, and b must be zero?

Comment: How about $a=1$?

Answer (score 1):

If $X \sim Gamma(\lambda, \theta)$, then p.d.f. of $X$ is

$$
f_X(x) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(\lambda)\theta^\lambda}x^{\lambda-1}e^{-\frac{x}{\theta}}.
$$

$Y = aX + b \sim f_Y(y) = \frac{1}{\Gamma(\lambda)\theta^\lambda}(\frac{y-b}{a})^{\lambda-1}e^{-\frac{y-b}{a\theta}}.$

The latter is a p.d.f. of exponential distribution only if

$$
\lambda = 1\text{ and }b = 0 \Rightarrow
$$

$$
f_Y(y) = \frac{1}{a\theta}e^{-\frac{y}{a\theta}},
$$

which is a p.d.f. of exponential distribution $Exp(a\theta).$

$$
a \text{ must be } > 0.
$$

But, if $\lambda = 1$, it means that $X$ is also exponential:

$$
Gamma(\lambda = 1, \theta) = Exp(\theta).
$$

Comment: Gotta add $b=0$, because $b\neq 0$ would make the whole integration $\neq 1$.